# python imaplib: Do I have to call .close() only once?

Tags: python, imaplib

the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) say:

> IMAP4.close()
>      Close currently selected mailbox. Deleted messages are removed from writable mailbox. This is the recommended command before LOGOUT.

I'd like to iterate over all mailboxes of an account (opening them readony btw).
Do I have to call .close() only once when I'm done, before logging out?
Or do I have to call it every time before opening another mailbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IMAP 'CLOSE' command according to RFC 1730 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1730#section-6.4.2 mentions that it is faster to call 'CLOSE' on each mailbox, but is not necessary.

Python's imaplib close() method just passes the 'CLOSE' request along to the server, the python docs just follow the RFC by saying 'recommended'.